# Openiddict refresh/access token not working on multiple servers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, openiddict

We have used asp.net identity for authentication and integrated openiddict in it. in our case when our app is running on a single server it works fine but when it is running on load balance (multiple servers) in some cases (i.e,) Access token was issued by server 1, and that access token is not accepted by server 2 it throws 401 error.

We have enabled reference tokens [pls check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i47R7.png)

After adding
**services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToDbContext()**

asp.net identity works fine in multiple servers but, there is still an issue in openiddict

[API call error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFxmc.png) & [token error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuJqp.png) => This error occurs when server 1 token is used in server 2

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share more of your code and the exact error message?

Comment: @LajosArpad I have updated and attached the error message

Comment: isnt this the same problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42628862/openiddict-401-errors-when-two-or-more-service-instance-count

Comment: yes @Oscar This is almost the problem I'm having, but I haven't been able to solve it by following the methods listed.